# How can I print exactly which input value coincides from a set I'm comparing against?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def no_num():
    invalid_char = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
    while True:
        invalid_char_counter = 0
        user_input = input()
        for char in invalid_char:
            if char in user_input:
                invalid_char_counter = 1
        if invalid_char_counter == 0:
            print(f'Success: {user_input} has no numbers.')
        else:
            print(f'Error: {user_input} has a number detected. Number(s) detected:')
            
            
no_num()
```

I want to check if the input contains any numbers. The code above does that, but in the "Success" or "Error" message, I want to return exactly which number from the input() is contained in the invalid_char set by saying "Number(s) detected:"

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you want all invalid chars (in the case where there are multiple) or just the first one?

Comment: @001 All, if possible

Comment: There are many ways. For example, since `invalid_char` is a set: `invalid_char.intersection(user_input)`. Maybe get rid of `invalid_char` and use regex: `re.findall(r"\d", user_input)`. There are a few more options in the answers below and many more.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another array and add your invalid char like this:

```
invalid_array = []

if char in user_input:
     invalid_char_counter = 1
     invalid_array.append(char)
```

However, a more Pythonic approach to your entire problem might be to use a filter like this:

```
user_input = input("Input your phrase: ")

#Function that we will use to filter
def is_number(x):
    return x.isnumeric()

#Filter out input to only contain numbers
search_result = list(filter(is_number, user_input))

if search_result: #If search_result is not empty
    counter = len(search_result)
    print(f'{counter} Numbers found: {search_result}')
else:
    print("No numbers found")
```

You can also look into lambdas in order to simplify the filter even further.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
def no_num():
    user_input = input()
    num = []
    for c in user_input:
        if c.isdigit():
            num.append(int(c))

    if num:
        print(f'Error: {user_input} has a number detected. Number(s) detected: {num}')
    else:
        print(f'Success: {user_input} has no numbers.')


no_num()
```

Output:

```
testing4numbers2
Error: testing4numbers2 has a number detected. Number(s) detected: [4, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a list comprehension or the filter function to build a list of invalid characters found in the user's input.  If there are any characters in the list, you print them out otherwise the string if valid.

```
def no_num():
    invalid_char = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
    while True:
        user_input  = input()
        invalids    = [c for c in user_input if c in invalid_char]
        if invalids:
            print('Error:',user_input,
                  'has a number detected. Number(s) detected:',
                  *invalids))            
        else:
            print(f'Success: {user_input} has no numbers.')

no_num()
```

If you only need to print invalid characters once (instead of every repeated occurrence of each), you can use set operations directly:

```
def no_num():
    invalid_char = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
    while True:
        user_input = input()
        if invalid_char.isdisjoint(user_input):
            print(f'Success: {user_input} has no numbers.')
        else:
            print('Error:',user_input,
                  'has a number detected. Number(s) detected:',
                  *invalid_char.intersection(user_input))
```